# Where a Number Occur More than or equal to N/3 Times

Tags: hash

Find number which is occur more than N/3 times in array. not N/2 times? just look at question first.

Without Using Moore's Algorithms.

Comment: Boyer-Moore algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to take into account the maximum (What is your worst scenario).
Unless you have not checked all elements in your array, 2 can compete till the end.

Lets assume you have the following array:

[1,2,3,1,2,2,1,2]

- when you are at element 4, 1 is the winner with a count of 2.
- at element 5, 1 & 2 are equal represented.
- at element 6, 2 is the winner with a count of 3.
- etc.

Based on this example you can see you will need to run over all of teh elements one time: O(n)